# Способ открыть файл json

Tags: java

В папке resources проекта у меня лежит папка lang. В ней файл ru_RU.json. Каким способом возможно его открыть и получить значение?

Comment: Хз как из ресурсов, а вот из ассетов - читаем в строку содержимое и юзаем либу типа Gson.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349759/using-json-file-in-android-app-resources

Comment: Можно подробнее про ассеты?)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел способ на просторах сообщеста:

```
// Android
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_file);
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
try {
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    int n;
    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
} finally {
    is.close();
}

String jsonString = writer.toString();


// Java
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("file/test.xml").getFile());
```

[Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349759/using-json-file-in-android-app-resources)/[Native Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

Comment: я тоже встречал этот способ, но не понял как правильно указать путь к файлу если он находится в resources проекта.

Comment: @ДинарЗарипов, `R` - это у Вас уже ресурс и потом Вы просто по структуре списка смотрите откуда всё грузить

Comment: скорее всего, этот метод для андроид приложений

Comment: А Вам для нативной джавы нужен?

Comment: @ДинарЗарипов, добавил вариант для нативной джавы